# How can I read from and write to a local directory from any self-hosted Wordpress blog page using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, file-io

I want to read and write text files to /data/filename.txt using php. This functionality works fine on the main page, but if I click the Previous Entries button (which switches to page 2), the php script does not seem to be present (as the Flash files are unable to access it).

Comment: Previous entries? Flash files? Please give some more background here :)

Comment: www.consolebias.com - On the front page, the Flash files have no problem talking to the php script, which reads and writes data to text files. If you scroll down and click "Previous Entries," which displays the second page of posts, the Flash files are unable to communicate with the php script, and display no data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your site correctly, your Flash tries to load data from `http://www.consolebias.com/text_poll.php`. You probably coded this link as just `text_poll.php` in your Flash file. This works on the homepage, but not on a page that has a URL that looks like it comes from another directory, like `http://consolebias.com/page/2` (even if it is a "fake" directory, the browser, where Flash runs, doesn't know that). Here, the Flash object tries to load the data from `http://consolebias.com/page/text_poll.php`, which doesn't exist.

If you change the reference of `text_poll.php` to `/text_poll.php`, it will always load it from the root, and it should work.